# "Split" files in single branch to create two branches

Tags: git, github, branch

I'm currently looking for a way to "split" the content of an existing Git branch (let's say, `dev`) within a git repository, to create two branches (let's say, `dev-ui` and `dev-backend`), each one containing half of the data of the original.

The use case here, is that I'd like to have two distinct branches for specific purposes (i.e. one for UI work, and the other for backend work, for example) that can both merge into the repository's main branch.

I've had a look at creating a couple of orphaned branches, each with half of the code from the original, but they don't share commit history therefore I'm unable to merge these into the `main` branch in Github.

If anyone has any ideas how to accomplish anything similar, whether the exact functionality above, or something completely different but accomplishes a similar goal, I'm all ears! Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You'll be better off creating two new repositories, as in [zer0's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72932065/1256452). Note that a repository doesn't contain files directly, and *branch* is poorly defined: a repository contains *commits*. Commits store snapshots and metadata. The snapshots are read-only archives in which you find a copy of *every* file that goes with that particular commit. (The file data are de-duplicated, so when commits re-use earlier or later commits' files, there's really only one copy after all—but *logically speaking* each commit has a full copy.)

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a better idea to create two new repositories for `ui` and `backend` and then add those as `git submodules` to your main `app` repository. This is the cleanest approach. You can read more about `submodules` [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules). You can then "synchronise" the module in your parent application, and each branch, since it will be created on the submodule repo, will only have the files of either `ui` or `backend`.

Trying to create branches that have inherently different data is not doable, I think, since all branches, by design must share, the same data as the parent branch, otherwise, like you said, the merge will not work and forcing a merge will delete the files from the parent that were deleted in the branch you're trying to merge.